# Python 3.10 antlr parser

Tags: python-3.x, antlr4

I have been using an [antlr v4 grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) to parse code for my [UML diagrammer](https://github.com/hasii2011/PyUt).  I would like to just replace my current 3.6 .g4 file with a 3.10 one.  My current grammar does not support the new Python `match` statement.

I found the [following](https://github.com/RobEin/ANTLR4-Python-grammar-by-PEG) but it generates Java code.  I need one that generates Python code.

Does anyone know if such a thing exists?

Comment: Have you tried the [combined Python2/3](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/python/python) or [straight Python3](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/python/python3) grammars in the grammars-v4 repo? Both target the Python3 runtime as well as a few other targets.

Comment: Nevermind.I see you have. Easy to extend, will do in a day or two.

Comment: Very preliminary, e.g., missing semantic predicates. https://github.com/kaby76/grammars-v4/tree/issue-2929/python/python3

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response.  
  
  
Worked on this today  

After some minor package modifications to Python3LexerBase, generating a visitor and including it my package this executed.  


However, it generated 30 syntax errors on some valid Python 3 code.  Not sure if this is related to your comment above about _missing semantic predicates_.  


`line 65:18 no viable alternative at input 'eventType' '

Comment: I am still working on the grammar. But, it would be best if you post the source as an attached file on a comment on https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/pull/2930. Then I can determine why it's not working and fix it.

Comment: The merge of this happened today;  This update works great with Python 3.10 code; For me other than a minor file edit to Python3LexerBase to account for my package structure, it was essentially a drop-in replacement once I generated the new code. Thanks for this work